# `std::filesystem::path::operator/(/*args*/)` not working as expected

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, std-filesystem

I have a class with an initialiser list in the constructor where one of the fields I'm initialising is a `std::filesystem::path` but it doesn't seem to be initialising to the expected value.

```cpp
MyClass::MyClass(
    unsigned int deviceSerial,
    const std::string& processName
) :
    deviceSerial(deviceSerial),
    processName(processName),
    configFilePath(GetBasePath() / std::to_string(deviceSerial) / ("#" + processName + ".json"))
{
    /* Parameter checks */
}
```

Using the debugger I can see that `GetBasePath()` is returning exactly what I expect (returns `std::filesystem::path` with correct path) but the `/` operator doesn't seem to be having an effect. Once inside the body of the constructor I can see that `configFilePath` is setup to the result of `GetBasePath()` without the extra info appended.

I'm using MSVS-2019, I have the C++ language standard set to C++17 and in debug mode I have all optimisations disabled.

I have also tested the following in the body of the class and I still see `path` as simply the result of `GetBasePath()` and the extra items are not being appended.

```cpp
{
    auto path = GetBasePath();             // path = "C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Devices"
    path /= std::to_string(deviceSerial);  // path = "C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Devices"
    path /= ("#" + processName + ".json"); // path = "C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Devices"
}
```

On a slight side note I also tried the above test with `+=` instead of `/=` and I still see the same results.

## Edit

As requested, below is a minimal complete and verifiable example.

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <filesystem>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

std::string ExpandPath(const std::string &str) {
  auto reqBufferLen = ExpandEnvironmentStrings(str.c_str(), nullptr, 0);

  if (reqBufferLen == 0) {
    throw std::system_error((int)GetLastError(), std::system_category(),
                            "ExpandEnvironmentStrings() failed.");
  }

  auto buffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(reqBufferLen);
  auto setBufferLen =
      ExpandEnvironmentStrings(str.c_str(), buffer.get(), reqBufferLen);

  if (setBufferLen != reqBufferLen - 1) {
    throw std::system_error((int)GetLastError(), std::system_category(),
                            "ExpandEnvironmentStrings() failed.");
  }

  return std::string{buffer.get(), setBufferLen};
}

int main() {
  unsigned int serial = 12345;
  std::string procName = "Bake";

  std::filesystem::path p(ExpandPath("%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\Devices"));
  std::printf("Path = %s\n", p.string().c_str());
  // p = C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Devices

  p /= std::to_string(serial);
  std::printf("Path = %s\n", p.string().c_str());
  // p = C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Devices

  p /= "#" + procName + ".json";
  std::printf("Path = %s\n", p.string().c_str());
  // p = C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Devices

  std::getchar();
}

I've also used this example and tested with `p.append()` and got the same result.
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This is more of a guess, but try the fs::append() method.

Comment: "Using the debugger" That may very well be your issue. How the path data is stored within the class is implementation specific, and may be hinding things from you. You should make sure this is reproducible through the class' interface (i.e. print the concatenated path to the console)

Comment: @rustyx Please see the above edit for a complete example.
@Mansoor As you suggested I've also tested `path::append()` and this gives the same result
@Frank In making the edited example I've removed all layers of abstraction, and I've also tested outside of the debugger when built in release mode. Still no difference.

Comment: Sorry, missed the `#include`s in the MCVE, should now compile, although M.M good spot on that bug :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to give thanks to @rustyx and @Frank for their suggestions, following this advice has led me to discover a bug in the way I create the initial string that gets passed to the path constructor (Also @M.M who found the exact bug while I was typing this answer)

I created a function (that is in use in my class) `std::string ExpandPath(const std::string& path)` which uses the Windows API to expand any environment variables in a path and return a string. This string is generated from a `char*` and a count, that count includes the null byte so when creating an string using the constructor variant `std::string(char* cstr, size_t len)` this includes the null byte in the string itself.

Because I was using the debugger to interrogate the variables it reads C-style strings and stops at the null byte. In my original example I also use `printf()` as I just happen to prefer this function for output, but again this stops printing at the null byte. If I change the output to use `std::cout` I can see that the output has the expected path but with an extra space their (the null byte being printed as a space). Using `std::cout` I see that my paths result as the following with each append:

```
Path = C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Devices
Path = C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Devices \12345
Path = C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Devices \12345\#Bake.json
```

---

#### Summary:

Bug in **my** `ExpandPath()` where

```cpp
  return std::string{buffer.get(), setBufferLen};
```

Should be

```cpp
  return std::string{buffer.get(), setBufferLen - 1};
```